# tailwind - @screen not generate media queries in scss

Tags: angular, sass, tailwind-css

**Angular 12 && tailwind ^3.0.12**

After compilation screen should generate media queries based on breakpoint but nothing generate

```
section {
  @apply w-full px-6 py-24;

  @screen sm {
    @apply py-14;
  }
  @screen md {
    @apply px-0 py-20 max-w-5xl mx-auto;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using screen directive at the top level.

```
section {
  @apply w-full px-6 py-24;
}

@screen md {  
  section {
     @apply px-0 py-20 max-w-5xl mx-auto;
  } 
}
```

Comment: Thank you. it worked but it's not a clean way to do that because I have a lot of selectors and put each of them on the whole @screen it becomes clumsy. a better way is to put each media in each selector